# Agile, Scrum and documentation

Tags: agile, scrum

One of the Four Core Agile values says *"Working Software over comprehensive documentation"* and this is explained as a good thing. Furthermore it is explained that rather than written communication (e-mails included), face-to-face meetings are preferred and "more productive".

I would like for someone to explain to me why or how is this a good thing?

In a organization I used to work there were heaps of working software that I had to maintain. The documentation was minimal and it was a nightmare. It didn't help that the programs were not modularized and were very hard to understand and with the most esoteric twists and very disorganized. Comprehensive documentation as very important was one think I took from that experience. It doesn't matter if the software works now if it is not going to work in the near future right?

And on face-to-face meetings, I had the same doubt. I very much prefer e-mails (written) You can say the most outrageous of things when talking but when it is written then it is a deal. Plus if you are in a multinational organization with several languages, it helps a lot

I would like to hear the voice of people with Agile experience. How is the above a good thing? Thanks

Comment: It's because you missed the line under it: "That is, while there is value in the items on the right, we value the items on the left more."

Comment: umm, well yes, in the values, say that but one book about Agile says literally "the most efficient and effective method of conveying information to and within a development team is face-to-face conversation"...mmm.. I don't buy this that much...whenever something crucial comes I prefer to say "put it in a mail and send it to me" (that way I can review it once and again and make sure it goes as planned-no?) what is wrong in my assumptions?

Comment: Software has to be intuitive, people like to discover by themselves, easily, rather than asking someone, because it's faster

Answer (score 1):

### Working software over comprehensive documentation

Comprehensive documentation is sometimes seen as a way to demonstrate progress. "If we have a detailed specification and a weighty design document then we are making good progress towards a product delivery"

What *working software over comprehensive documentation* means is that we view working software as a better demonstration of progress than documentation. This is because comprehensive documentation can give a false level of confidence.

So there is nothing that says avoid doing any documentation. It is just saying that we should *only do the documentation that is needed and not just do documentation because it is part of a process*.

In your example where there the software is difficult to work with then more documentation may well be *needed*. Just don't write documents that never get used and offer little value.

### Individuals and interaction over process and tools

Face-to-face communication has many advantages over other forms of communication. For example:

- People use body language to give context to conversations
- People use audible and visual clues as to when to start and stop talking - this helps to make conversations flow
- Regular face-to-face discussions often help teams to bond together

Notice though that the Agile manifesto does not mention face-to-face communication. All it says is *individuals and interaction*. If you and your team have ways of communicating that are as effective as face-to-face communication then that fits just as well within the Agile approach. The important part is that we value interaction and having members of the team work closely with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is an expression of a shared vocabulary, so it should be consistent from the epic all the way down to the comments in the code:

> Documentation should be comprehensive and understandable.  Using examples is recommended.

Language between feature stories, technical stories, pseudocode, and assertions should have naming conventions

> A feature that people do not know about is a useless feature.

Lack of documentation can be a symptom of the lack of a marketing plan

> A feature that isn't documented is a useless feature.  A patch for a new feature must include the documentation.

Lack of documentation can be a symptom of the lack of usability, accessibility, and information architecture

> Adjust the documentation.  Doing this first gives you an impression of how
> your changes affect the user.

Lack of documentation can be a symptom of a lack of focus on the user and the maintainer:

> Software is not useful by itself. The executable software is only part of the picture. It is of no use without user manuals, business processes, design documentation, well-commented source code, and test cases. These should be produced as an intrinsic part of the development, not added at the end. In particular, recognize that design documentation serves two distinct purposes:
>
> To allow the developers to get from a set of requirements to an implementation. Much of this type of documentation outlives its usefulness after implementation.
>
> To allow the maintainers to understand how the implementation satisfies the requirements. A document aimed at maintainers is much shorter, cheaper to produce and more useful than a traditional design document.

And understanding the purpose of any project requires building a relationship between the project timeline and the source code history:

> Write the change log entries for your changes. This is both to save us the extra work of writing them, and to help explain your changes so we can understand them.
>
> The purpose of the change log is to show people where to find what was changed. So you need to be specific about what functions you changed; in large functions, it’s often helpful to indicate where within the function the change was.
>
> On the other hand, once you have shown people where to find the change, you need not explain its purpose in the change log. Thus, if you add a new function, all you need to say about it is that it is new. If you feel that the purpose needs explaining, it probably does — but put the explanation in comments in the code. It will be more useful there.

**References**

- [Vim documentation: develop](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/develop.html)
- [SCRUM-PSP: Embracing Process Agility and Discipline (pdf)](https://ts.data61.csiro.au/publications/nictaabstracts/4164.pdf)
- [Secure Software Development Life Cycle Processes | US-CERT](https://www.us-cert.gov/bsi/articles/knowledge/sdlc-process/secure-software-development-life-cycle-processes)
- [An Uneasy Marriage? Merging Scrum and TSP (pdf)](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a557855.pdf)
- [TSP/PSP and Agile-SCRUM: Similarities & Differences](https://www.slideshare.net/strongstep/agile-portugal-2012-tsppsp-and-agilescrum-similarities-differences-study-csar-duarte)
- [GNU Emacs Manual: Sending Patches](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Sending-Patches.html#Sending-Patches)

Answer (score 0):

When all agile recommendations are taken into account there are no issues you mentioned in your question. Working software should also has good code standards and design.

Regarding your particular issue with a lack of documentation unit tests (TDD/BDD) could be very useful. Good code coverage can explain how code should work even better than detailed documentation. Agile methodology also welcomes simplicity so your entire architecture might be over-complicated

Regarding face-to-face communication. Just imagine situation when you detected issue in your product (web-site markup). Instead of writing long email with steps to reproduce and attaching screenshots, you just go to front-end developer sitting in your room or make skype call and start explaining problem. Developer quickly realizes that he forgot to include some script. So your will get answer in minutes while your email can be answered next day.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be necessary to clarify your needs on using agile first before you want to apply agile.

Agile is the recommended working framework for a highly unpredictable domain(you may also check Cynefin model for identifying your working contexts). In this domain, you do require "working software" and "good communication" to review and revise your development in a short-term iterative process. As a result, you can change and improve your software based on the feedback from your software. This is proven to be the most effective and efficient way to build software in high competitive business world.

However, in your organization, you are maintaining legacy software with limited documentation. This context is totally different from what agile is designed for. You need optimization in your world, not testing or growth seeking. In short, process/tools and documentation are more important.

Regarding email communication, there is no doubt that email makes the deal, but you could never make a deal by just using email. It is the same as how you apply agile. You should apply both face-to-face and email based on different situation.

I would regard Agile as a framework more than a methodology. The concept there is to allow you build your own process based on your own working environment.